# CSV file missing some fields when opening with pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

when opening csv file with pandas `read_csv`, I noticed missing text from the output. See screen shot of the what the CSV file looks like when opened normally and also when opened using pandas `read_csv`:

[image]

I tried to execute `csv_read` on the csv file instead of the txt file but I'm getting the same results.

```
with open('intC.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in output:
        f.write(line)

with open('intC.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        print(line)

data = pd.read_csv('intC.txt')
print('\n')
print(data)
```

Comment: The ellipses seems to suggest it's not showing the full dataset. Are you sure the all the data isn't there?

Comment: all the data is in the original file. the first print statement prints the entire intC.txt output; no idea why read_csv on that same file is not showing the full output. Further, i converted the text file to a csv file and executed read_csv directly on the converted file; no dice. However if i open the csv file on Excel spreadsheet, it has all the dataset. The question really is why read_csv isn't displaying the full dataset. I'm trying to sort the output by the 'RXBS' column so it's important I have everything printed and displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

They are not "missing", this just basically mean that they are too long to be printed in full. You can edit panda's settings by displaying all using the following

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

Comment: Thanks: where do i add the line? I added it just before this: 

data = pd.read_csv('intC.txt')

No dice.

Comment: @wuki Is this on jupyter notebook or cmd?

Answer (score 0):

`pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)` alone didn't work; these three lines together work - i find that weird:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)  
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually tried running it with just this line and it also worked:

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
```